# How to set a delegate view controller class in a "model" component in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I have a view controller class in Swift where the view is a separate class and I connect it via an outlet to the view controller. This allows me to set the view controller class as the view's delegate in the `didset` method:

```
@IBOutlet theView: ViewClass! {
    didSet {
        theView.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

But I also try to separate most of my apps backend logic into a separate class (model in MVC) and I create this in my view controller like this:

```
let logic = Logic()
```

but I have no good way for `Logic` to do some background work and inform my view controller of things. I'd like to, similarly, pass in the view controller as a delegate class to `Logic`. Where is the best place to do so? I get a strange "invalid argument type list" error if I try to do this in MyViewController:

```
let logic = Logic(self)
```

presumably because of initialization ordering of `self`? What's the correct place/best way of doing this?

Comment: Does `Logic` have a delegate property, or what init methods?

Comment: You can create a method in Logic where you pass in a callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you having a look at this course by Stanford university and having a look at the MVC lectures: https://itunes.apple.com/gb/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099

They recommend using `NSNotifcation`s to let your controller know of changes in the model and only using delegates to notify of changes in views. Have a look at this to learn more about `NSNotifcation`: http://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/08/fundamentals-of-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift/